# NameError: name 'self' is not defined" when using inside with statement

Tags: python, class, nameerror, contextmanager

Can someone help me about using 'self' inside 'with'. 
Code below throws "NameError: name 'self' is not defined".

```
class Versions:

    def __init__(self):
        self.module_a = '1.0.0'
        self.module_b = '1.0.0'

        if os.path.exists('config.json'):
            with open('config.json') as f:
                configs = json.load(f)
                for config in configs:
                    setattr(self, config, configs[config])
```

Traceback

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ed6a4ca551d4> in <module>()
      3                 configs = json.load(f)
      4                 for config in configs:
----> 5                         setattr(self, config, configs[config])
      6

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Aside: you can unindent the for loop

Comment: The code you have in this question is correct, maybe you have some indentation problem that lets Python think the if statement isn't inside the def.

Comment: This code fails in IPython shell. But works if executed as script. obviously Its more of a shell thing but i got stuck there for a while :-|. Thanks for the reply guys.

Answer (score 2):

please check Your indentation - if You mix spaces and tabs, this can happen; use $python -tt to verify. Your code snippet works fine for me.

Comment: do you have config.json file in palce?

Comment: Yes, I checked with simple config file and without it - no exception happened.